# Codenameone list adding functionality

Tags: codenameone

I'm currently busy with a Codenameone app that requires me to add a list of items by button click like how you would add a task in a task list. How would I approach this? I'm a bit new at this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short example:

```
Form form = new Form("List Example");  //Create Form

Button button = new Button("PRESS ME"); //Create Button
form.add(button);  // add button to Form

List myList = new List<>(); //Create List
form.add(myList);  //add List to Form

// Create an Array of Elements 
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    arrayList.add("Elemnt " + i);
  }

// Create ListModel
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>(arrayList);

// Add Button ActionListner
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
  {
    myList.setModel(listModel);  //add ListModel to List
    form.repaint(); 
  }
});

form.show();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works!!

Comment: As an FYI I would suggest reading this: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html